# SSRS 2016 Datasource - SQL Server 2000 database

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, sql-server-2000, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2016

Looking to upgrade SSRS from 2008R2 to 2016.

Can SQL Server 2000 databases be used as data source in SSRS 2016? And are there any other known issues that could come up with the migration?

Comment: Can it be used? Sure, no guarantee that it works or continues to work though. SQL 2000 hasn't been supported for years so there is no reason to test SSRS with it which means it wasn't which means you're at your own risk. It's been 17 years, time for an upgrade where you know it's supported to work.

Comment: It can be used, with SSRS 2016, and For Migration use Migration Tools, first migrate it to 2008R2 that will support well in 2016, here migration depends on what technologies you have already implemented in SQL 2000, like if you have `dts` packages, that will require to upgrade manually, old Joins you need to upgrade, and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a data source from SSRS 2016 to a 2000 database so yes it is possible. However, as the commenters above stated it isn't supported.